# how to align textview to the upper right of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have the below layout. i want the textView with id tvName to be on the upper left and the textView with id tvAddress to be on the upper right of the screen as shown in the follwoing

tvName                             tvAddress

in the below code, I used layout_gravity attribute but it did not do what i want

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Address: "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add image of your desired design?

Comment: use layout_gravity in your LinearLayout

Comment: switch your layout use Relative layout or show us what you are getting and what you need so that we can help you

Answer (score 2):

**You can easily resolve with a relative layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:text="Name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:text="Address: "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**if you want the LinearLayout use this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:weightsum="2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:weight="1"
    android:text="Name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Address: "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address: "
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```